# Command in path not found

Tags: linux, bash, path

I've a command in the `~/.local/bin/` path (lets call it dog). Calling the command with the full path `~/.local/bin/dog` works as expected .

When I do `which dog` I get the expected `~/.local/bin/dog`. When I check the $PATH `~/.local/bin` is there as it should (actually it is `/home/ec2-user/.local/bin`)

But if simply type `dog` I get the following error:

`-bash: /usr/local/bin/dog: No such file or directory`

The output for `type dog` is `dog is hashed (/usr/local/bin/dog)`
But for `type -a dog` is `dog is /home/ec2-user/.local/bin/dog`

Ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you should run the command `hash -r`. From [John1024's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/446583):

> If you update your system and, as a result, some executable moves to a
>   new location, the shell may get confused. The solution is to run hash
>   -r which causes the shell to forget all the hashed locations and search the PATH from scratch.