# command invocation location is inconsistent with `which` command output

Tags: centos, binary, which

I'm installing `protocolbuf` on my CentOS 7 box, and after installation, I saw some inconsistency while running the `protoc` compiler binary:

```
$  which protoc
/usr/local/bin/protoc 
$  protoc
bash: /bin/protoc: No such file or directory
```

This definitely looks wrong, how do I fix this problem?

Comment: could do a sym link from /bin/protoc to /usr/local/bin/protoc. 
There is probably a better way but that would make it run.

Comment: What does `type protoc` say?

Comment: @StephenHarris it says `protoc is hashed (/bin/protoc)`

Comment: That sounds like you used to have a `/bin/protoc` but removed it.  So try `hash -r`.  That will cause `bash` to forget the old name and look on the path again.

Comment: that works -  it says `protoc is hashed (/usr/local/bin/protoc)` and `protoc` is working fine, thank you! @StephenHarris

Comment: This is https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/535632/5132 and https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/82991/5132 and https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/474116/5132 again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With modern shells they *remember* the path to a command you previously ran.  So, for example:

```
bash-4.2$ hash
hash: hash table empty
bash-4.2$ whoami
sweh
bash-4.2$ hash
hits    command
   1    /usr/bin/whoami
```

Now if you remove a program (in your case `/bin/protoc`) and install it in a new location (`/usr/local/bin/protoc`) the current shell will try the old location.  And it fails, because the old file isn't there.

You can tell the shell to forget all remembered paths with `hash -r`.

That will force it to search the path again.

The `which` command doesn't understand the current shell's hash.  The `type` command is a shell builtin that's more accurate.